# RoR sort/scope/filter via button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I came across this site:

https://tutorials.railsapps.org/rails-tutorial

And was wondering if someone could explain how the buttons would be set up to filter?

I guess I'm curious also - is an object being displayed and filtered? What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is not Rails but Javascript.

When you click the 'Beginner' button, it has an attribute `data-toggle="Beginner"` and uses javascript to show only the elements below that have a class `Beginner`.

It would look something like this using jQuery in coffeescript:

`$('.filters li[data-toggle]').on 'click', ->
  toggle = $(this).data('toggle')
  $("div.tutorial:not(.#{toggle})").hide()
  $("div.tutorial.#{toggle}").show()`

To serve up the html classes would be Rails' job.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still questioning the fact that it seems like you would be passing all "results" through, and you would do the filtering on that. Seems like that might be a little bit of a resource hog (IMO), but this is a good start.